# How to programmatically detect sata drive unplug in SuSE Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, sata

Does anyone know of a method I can use to programmatically detect if a SATA hard drive has been unplugged?  Our file system is mounted in READ-ONLY mode when we need to detect the removal of the drive.  We noticed the other day that we were able to unplug a hard drive and everything continued to run without a hitch until the next time we attempted to read from a file on disk.

Comment: Not a full answer, but doesn't SUSE add on to the `dmesg` whenever a SATA drive gets unplugged? You could get the dmesg and continually poll it for harddrive changes.

Comment: Crap, I forgot an additional complication.  Our file system is in READ-ONLY mode when I need to detect the disconnect.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing the output of `dmesg` is a bad idea for several reasons, not the least of which it being inefficient and dependent on the format that the `printk` in the kernel happens to use.

On modern Linux systems, hardware changes are usually handled through [udev](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kernel/hotplug/udev.html) which, in turn, will propagate change events up through [D-BUS](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus).

You may want to search how the insert and removal of memory sticks is handled; the methods should be fairly similar.